# E0513 a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: visual-c++

hi im trying to draw a window on the screen and i wrote this 2 weeks ago and it worked but now i rewrote it exactly the same and im getting errors? can anyone help?
The errors are:
**E0167 argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"**  (and)   **E0513 a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"**

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<d2d1.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    }
    DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPWSTR cmd, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX windowclass;
    ZeroMemory(&windowclass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    windowclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    windowclass.hInstance = hinstance;
    windowclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    windowclass.lpszClassName = "CrystalWindow";
    windowclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&windowclass);

    HWND windowHandle = CreateWindow("CrystalWindow", "Crystal Engine", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hinstance, 0);

    if (!windowHandle)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(windowHandle, nCmdShow);

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `W` in `LPCWSTR` stands for `wide`.

You are passing the narrow characters, while you program is compiled as UNICODE.

You can either add a prefix `L` to all you strings or use a `_T()` macro.

For example:

```
windowclass.lpszClassName = L"CrystalWindow";
```